# What's the 'safest' way to read from this buffer?

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, buffer, port

I'm trying to read and write a serial port in Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) where a microcontroller on the other end blasts 1 or 3 bytes whenever it finishes a certain task. I'm able to successfully read and write to the device, but the problem is my reads are a little 'dangerous' right now:

```
do
{
    nbytes = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    usleep(50000);
} while(nbytes == -1);
```

I.e. to simply monitor what the device is sending me, I poll the buffer every half second. If it's empty, it idles in this loop. If it receives something or errors, it kicks out. Some logic then processes the 1 or 3 packets and prints it to a terminal. A half second is usually a long enough window for something to fully appear in the buffer, but quick enough for a human who will eventually see it to not think it's slow.

'Usually' is the keyword. If I read the buffer in the middle of it blasting 3 bytes. I'll get a bad read; the buffer will have either 1 or 2 bytes in it and it'll get rejected in the packet processing (If I catch the first of a 3 byte packet, it won't be a purposefully-sent-one-byte value).

Solutions I've considered/tried:

1. I've thought of simply reading in one byte at a time and feeding in additional bytes if its part of a 3 byte transmission. However this creates some ugly loops (as read() only returns the number of bytes of only the most previous read) that I'd like to avoid if I can
2. I've tried to read 0 bytes (eg nbytes = read(fd, buffer, 0);) just to see how many bytes are currently in the buffer before I try to load it into my own buffer, but as I suspected it just returns 0.

It seems like a lot of my problems would be easily solved if I could peek into the contents of the port buffer before I load it into a buffer of my own. But read() is destructive up to the amount of bytes that you tell it to read.

How can I read from this buffer such that I don't do it in the middle of receiving a transmission, but do it fast enough to not appear slow to a user? My serial messenger is divided into a sender and receiver thread, so I don't have to worry about my program loop blocking somewhere and neglecting the other half.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There are two errors in your code, one syntax error (missing semicolon), and one logical (assignment in `while` condition).

Comment: Nice catch. (I should probably always just copy-paste instead of transcribing it.)

Comment: It seems a bit silly to wait 50 ms after you successfully read some data.  Why not `while ((nbytes = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) == -1) usleep(50000);`?

Comment: What exactly is your microcontroller doing? Tell us a little more about it, and the protocol of the messages sent on the serial I/O line.

Comment: My microcontroller is basically a state machine that controls some buttons, sensors and LEDs. It's a school project to make a traffic light system that can be remotely controllable, like from a central office. Right as the microcontroller branches into a state, it sends a byte containing the state it's branching into, the onboard minute and onboard hour respepectively, each masked by the two MSBs of the byte. It responds to valid packets from the server with an ACK value, and initiates a connection to the server with another value, both one byte. Server can override state/time on uC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your packet processing.  I always end up using a state machine for instances like this, so that if I get a partial message, I remember (stateful) where I left off processing and can resume when the rest of the packet arrives.

Typically I have to verify a checksum at the end of the packet, before proceeding with other processing, so "where I left off processing" is always "waiting for checksum".  But I store the partial packet, to be used when more data arrives.

Even though you can't peek into the driver buffer, you can load all those bytes into your own buffer (in C++ a `deque` is a good choice) and peek into that all you want.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know how large the messages being sent are. There are a couple of ways to do that:

1. Prefix the message with the length of the message.
2. Have a message-terminator, a byte (or sequence of bytes) that can not be part of a message.
3. Use the "command" to calculate the length, i.e. when you read a command-byte you know how much data should follow, so read that amount.

The second method is best for cases when you can come out of sync, because then read until you get the message-terminator sequence and you're sure that the next bytes will be a new message.

You can of course combine these methods.

Answer (score 1):

To poll a device, you should better use a multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) which succeeds when some data is available for reading from that device. Notice that `poll` is multiplexing: you can poll several file descriptors at once, and `poll` will succeed as soon as one (any) file descriptor is readable with `POLLIN` (or writable, if so asked with `POLLOUT`, etc...).

Once `poll` succeeded for some `fd` which you `POLLIN` you can [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) from that `fd`

Of course, you need to know the conventions used by the hardware device about its messages. Notice that a single `read` could get several messages, or only a part of one (or more). There is no way to prevent reading of partial messages (or "packets") - probably because your PC serial I/O is much faster than the serial I/O inside your microcontroller. You should bear with that, by knowing the conventions defining the messages (and if you can change the software inside the microcontroller, define an easy convention for that) and implementing the appropriate state machine and buffering, etc...

<sup>NB: There is also the older [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) syscall for multiplexing, which has limitations related to the C10K problem. I recommend `poll` instead of `select` in new code.</sup>

Comment: You *cannot prevent* read of partial packets. As I said, you need to know the conventions defining these messages, and you need to handle the partial messages (by relevant buffering).

Comment: You'll probably get partial packets as soon as the serial controller on the motherboard is faster than the one inside your external microcontroller, which is probably always the case. So you cannot avoid partial packets. You have to handle them!

Comment: When I posted that comment, your answer said nothing about actually handling partial packets (which is the only right answer)

Comment: No, using `poll` (or maybe `select`) is much more sensible than `read` then `usleep` ...), and `poll` is useful even if each "message" (or "packet") was exactly one byte.

Comment: Well, he should be using the serial port timeout, not `usleep`.  `poll` doesn't really have an advantage until he tries to interleave access to multiple file descriptors.